# Look at a hash, find the first key where value is nil, do something with that key/value pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iterator, block

I'm writing this complex loop structure and would love to make filling my hash a little easier.

At the beginning of my method, I make something that looks like this:

```
thing_array = [{
animals: nil,
fruit: nil,
cars: nil
},
{
animals: nil,
fruit: nil,
cars: nil
},
{
animals: nil,
fruit: nil,
cars: nil
}]
```

My goal is to loop through the array, and then each hash, find the first element that's nil and set that key/value pair based on the value of the loop that runs outside of this.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Tin Man said you'll need to make your question clearer. The method below gets you to the first nil value in the array. I wasn't sure what you wanted to do once you got to that point, but hopefully this helps!

```
def getFirstNil(array)
   array.each do |hash|
      hash.each do |key,value|
         if value == nil
            #here's your first nil, do something!
            return key
         end
      end
   end
   return nil
end
```